# Применить php скрипт, в отношении пользователя, которому принадлежит <button>

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.

У меня на сайте есть список пользователей, который выводится циклом из бд при помощи php, пример:

```
<div class="user">
   <p>Иван</p><button type="button">Редактировать пользователя</button>
</div>
<div class="user">
   <p>Олег</p><button type="button">Редактировать пользователя</button>
</div>
<div class="user">
   <p>Антон</p><button type="button">Редактировать пользователя</button>
</div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку "Редактировать пользователя", например, у Антона, нужно чтобы открывалась страница редактирования пользователя, которая в свою очередь, применит внесенные на этой странице изменения только для Антона (И по аналогии с остальными пользователями).

Из идей на данный момент, это цеплять в цикле ссылку на кнопку (во время вывода списка пользователей) с GET параметром идентификатора пользователя и в дальнейшем в скрипте, опираться на этот самый GET. Вот что должно получиться:

```
<div class="user">
   <p>Иван</p><button href="/edituser?user_id=1" type="button">Редактировать пользователя</button>
</div>
<div class="user">
   <p>Олег</p><button href="/edituser?user_id=2" type="button">Редактировать пользователя</button>
</div>
<div class="user">
   <p>Антон</p><button href="/edituser?user_id=3" type="button">Редактировать пользователя</button>
</div>
```

Является ли данное решение оптимальным? Или существует другой, более лучший вариант решения данного вопроса.

Comment: Да, обычно так и делается. Только не забудьте валидировать данные

Comment: @r.mcreal Спасибо большое за ваш ответ! Значит буду реализовывать именно таким способом.

Answer (score 0):

на кнопку ссылку не ставят, попробуйте так

```
<div class="user">
<p>Иван</p><a href="/edituser?user_id=1" type="button">Редактировать пользователя</a>
</div>
<div class="user">
<p>Олег</p><a href="/edituser?user_id=2" type="button">Редактировать пользователя</a>
</div>
<div class="user">
<p>Антон</p><a href="/edituser?user_id=3" type="button">Редактировать пользователя</a>
</div>
```

на странице edituser по $_GET['user_id'] достаете всю инфу юсера и редактируете

если надо с кнопками то можно через форму

```
<form action="/edituser" method="POST">
<div class="user">
<p>Иван</p><button name="тут user_id" type="button">Редактировать пользователя</button>
</div>
<div class="user">
<p>Олег</p><button name="тут user_id" type="button">Редактировать пользователя</button>
</div>
<div class="user">
<p>Антон</p><button name="тут user_id" type="button">Редактировать пользователя</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: У кнопок надо user_id не в атрибут `name` писать, а в атрибут `value`, а в атрибут `name` можно написать, например, `"edit"` тогда в `$_POST` придет `"edit" => "user_id"` и `type` должен быть `"submit"`